# Creating a cronjob that runs at 3:00am, 3:50am, 9:00am, & 9:50am?

Tags: cron

How would I go about creating a cronjob that runs at the following times every day:

- 3:00am
- 3:50am
- 9:00am
- 9:50am

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
00,50    3,9    *    *    *    /usr/bin/something.sh
```

---

#### The Solution

After much poking around in the logs, it turns out the issue was another script higher up in the crontab was segfaulting so my crontab entry never ran at all.

I disabled those scripts and my entry ran just fine.  Also, it turns out that the syntax above is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `/usr/bin/something.sh` executable ?

Check

```
/var/log/cron or /var/log/messages
```

depending on your distribution.

Comment: For what it's worth, the script runs properly if I tweak the times in the crontab.  It seems to be an issue with how I was trying to do multiple minutes.

Comment: So, in the end, not a crontab syntax issue at all.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

```
0 3,9 * * * /usr/bin/something.sh
50 3,9 * * * /usr/bin/something.sh
```

Comment: Duh.  That seems so obvious now.

Comment: The two should be example, most crons accept ranges in any of the 5 fields. Which OS ?

Answer (score 3):

Both of the above are good answers/questions.  I ran across this yesterday and it might give you some ideas:

[Practical Crontab Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)